# Is it possible to set environment variable of one lambda from another

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a scenario where I need to set an environment variable of one lambda from another. The first lambda is an s3 trigger that will handle a csv uploaded to s3. It will then create a table in Dynamo by generating the table name with timestamp appended. I want to be able to make this lambda set an environment variable of another lambda that will be consuming the newly created table. Is it possible to do it and if so how do we do it in NodeJs?

Comment: This is almost certainly the wrong approach: it's equivalent to using global variables within your code, and if you ever have concurrent uploads it will cause problems (_ever_: even if you don't now, you might later).

Comment: Why don't you want to simply invoke the second lambda from the first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep this is possible.

For reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateFunctionConfiguration-property

```
var params = {
  FunctionName: 'Your-Function-Name', /* required */
  Environment: {
    Variables: {
      'TABLE_NAME': 'Your-New-Dynamo-Table-Name'
    }
  }
};
lambda.updateFunctionConfiguration(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Is it recommended approach (or possible) to modify environment variables for a lambda from the execution of same lambda (lambda to change it's own environment variable)?

I don't want any in between caching servers or DB.

Comment: Note that this will not modify the published version of the Lambda.  The [UpdateFunctionConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html) docs say: "_These settings can vary between versions of a function and are locked when you publish a version. You can't modify the configuration of a published version, only the **unpublished version**_."